# memoir class prevent mainmatter reset page number

Tags: memoir, page-numbering, appendices

How can I prevent my class based on `memoir` to reset the page counter for the second `\mainmatter`?

I have following layout:

```
\frontmatter
```

.....abstract, acknowledgement,table of content

```
\mainmatter
```

.....chapter1, usw

```
\backmatter
```

.....glosar, sources

```
\mainmatter
```

.....appendix chapter1,

The last `\mainmatter` acts as appendix but I wanted to have the same chapter layout so I used `\mainmatter` but I want to continue the page numbering?

Answer (score 3):

[`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides a starred version `\mainmatter*` that doesn't reset the page numbering.

Alternatively (if you're not using `memoir`), you can make `\pagenumbering` gobble it's argument so it turns into a no-op:

```
\frontmatter
...
\mainmatter
...
\backmatter
...
\renewcommand{\pagenumbering}[1]{}% Remove functionality of \pagenumbering
\mainmatter
...
```

Comment: sadly boh did not work for me. i solved it temporarly by adding a counter which saves the page number in the backmatter and than resetts the pagenumber to the saved value in the second mainmatter. i wand to add the function to my class file, so the tex file looks cleaner any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @MadMax: Hmmm. Can you provide me with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem? Then I'll have something tangible to work with.

Comment: @MadMax: Perhaps you may have used what I put down as `\pagenumber`. In fact, it should have been `\pagenumbering`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to continue the sequence of page numbers

```
\savepagenumber
\mainmatter
\restorepagenumber
```